# Polar coordinates of a parametric curve

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves

I have to find the polar coordinates of the following curve
$$\alpha(t)=(2+\cos(t),2+\sin(t))$$
for $t\in[0,2\pi]$. Using
$$x=r\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\theta$$
I found
$$r=\sqrt{9+4(\cos(t)+\sin(t)}$$
and
$$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{2+\cos(t)}{2+\sin(t)}\right)$$
My question is: am I right? Or is there a better and easier way to get it? I saw in a book that I should call $r=t$ but I don't know if it's the best way.